# New to iCloudKit, trying to access a common container

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

Got iCloud working well on app A. Want to share iCloud public database used by app A with App B.
Managed to link App B to App A iCloudKit, all looks good.
But struggling to understand the syntax behind specifying the CKcontainer for app B, if I simply use ...

CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [[CKContainer defaultContainer] publicCloudDatabase];

Obviously it goes for App B iCloudKit, which doesn't exist. But what is the syntax to specify a custom container?

CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [[CKContainer @"iCloud.com.blah.appa" publicCloudDatabase];

Doesn't even compile; sorry I know I should wade thru the documentation, but I was hoping somebody could simply post a snippet of code to get by this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Bon,

Thought about this over night and of course the answer is obvious.

CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [[CKContainer containerWithIdentifier:@"iCloud.com.blah.appa"] publicCloudDatabase];

Both compiles and works !

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same container, `[[CKContainer defaultContainer] publicCloudDatabase];` will return the same container for both app. You can init with identifier as well instead of the default containers.